# Javascript Object Database

Tags: javascript, database, object, orm

is there any javascript object database??

Something like http://www.db4o.com/ but for javascript?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML5 includes an [embedded SQL database](http://apirocks.com/html5/html5.html#slide8). You could write a tiny ORM around it to deal only in objects.

Checkout [ActiveJS](http://activerecordjs.org/index.html) and specifically [ActiveRecord](http://activerecordjs.org/record.html). It does not use the HTML5 Web SQL database currently, but has plans on supporting that.

Also a timeless post (no year anywhere), mentions [JStorm](http://www.urielkatz.com/archive/detail/introducing-jstorm/) but I'm not too familiar with it.

Is it needed for client-side, or server-side?

Comment: thanks, im not using javascript for the web, so i cannot use the html5 features, but i will check the activejs and activerecord :)

thanks

Comment: you might be interested in CouchDB (http://couchdb.apache.org/) or MongoDB (http://www.mongodb.org/) if it's not client side.

Comment: One of the merits gained via db4o is you can be free from writing or configuring or caring about ORM, and letting users write native Java language to define model and store them/query them as they are.

Comment: The first link is now dead; the latest version I could find is here: https://web.archive.org/web/20100429185247/http://apirocks.com/html5/html5.html#slide8 This seems to refer to the "Web SQL Database" which I believe is no longer in active maintenance.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for server side object oriented database for JavaScript, you can check http://wakandadb.org/ They have complete end-to-end solution for web / mobile development using JS as complete stack, check that at http://www.wakanda.org/

Wakanda is good NoSQL JS object database, but it might not be good for cloud based apps that need to soon scale out. Scaling out with will be an issues, which is a plus point with MongoDB, Cassandra or CouchDB kind of databases, but these data bases are not object-oriented, most of them are simply JSON stores.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at IndexedDB. [They](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/) refer to it as an "object store" all the time, and I think it can store arbitrary objects. Don't use WebSQL since it is now discontinued and doesn't support all JavaScript objects. See also Wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indexed_Database_API).